# How to create a popup in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a web application using JSF and Javascript. I have a question about how to open a pop-up and add information into it.

Indeed, i'm using html2canvas to get the image of the content of a HTML page.

This is the code of my js :

```
function openPopupWithScreenshot(){
    html2canvas($('#contentBody'), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            window.open(img);
        }
    });
}
```

And the code of my button in JSF:

```
<h:commandButton value="#{bundle.button_print}" onclick="openPopupWithScreenshot();"/>
```

The code works perfectly, when i click on the button, a popup appears with my image. But my problem is I want to add more information (stored in a Javabean) into my popup.

Schematically, i want that my popup displays my image and a String stored in my Javabean. I'm a noob in javascript and i don't know how to do.

Could you help me please?

Thank you.

EDIT :

I have tried this :

```
function ouvrirPopupAvecImprEcran(){
    html2canvas($('#contentBody'), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            var newImg = window.open(img);
            newImg.document.write("<title>TITLE</title>");
            newImg.document.write("<img src='"+ img.src +"'/>");
            newImg.document.write("<p>TEST</p>");
        }
    });
}
```

My popup appears correctly but my image is not display because it doesn't find the source of my image. How could i modify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You was almost there, try this:

```
function ouvrirPopupAvecImprEcran(){
    html2canvas(document.body, {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            var newImg = window.open();
            newImg.document.write("<title>TITLE</title>");
            newImg.document.write("<img src='"+ img +"'/>");
            newImg.document.write("<p>TEST</p>");
        }
    });
}
```

The image you created from canvas here `var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");` was not the HTML Element img. It was a string with data: URL, it's like an image encoded into string. 
To understand it better you could look at HTMLCanvasElement#toDataURL() method here http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement

Comment: Thank you andbas! Now, i will try to add parameters in my function.